# What's the difference between typical and maximum forward voltage for an LED?

Tags: led, datasheet

The [datasheet](https://cdn.evilmadscientist.com/catalog/components/semi/LED/datasheets/BL-L513.PDF) for some LEDs I'm considering lists the forward voltages as 2.7V typical and 4.2V max.  (I'm looking at the "warm white" version.)

In the past, I've only ever looked at the *typical* forward voltage for figuring out the resistor value.  But I've never used an LED where the maximum value may be so different from the typical.

What factors affect the actual forward voltage?  Manufacturing variation?  Temperature?  Current?  Something else?

Suppose I have a 3.3V supply and that I want to drive one of these LEDs at 20mA. Based on the 2.7V typical forward voltage, I'd use a 30 Ohm resistor.  But if I end up with an LED that actually has a forward voltage of 4.2V, it won't light because 4.2V > 3.3V.

How do you design a circuit to accommodate such a wide range of forward voltages, or is there a reason I don't have to worry about the max forward voltage?

Comment: Do you really want to drive these LEDs with maximum luminosity, all 20 mA? What is the purpose for your LEDs?

Comment: See my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353955/reqforhelp-understanding-vf-relationship-to-supplied-v-and-a/353975#353975 for some info on this topic.

Comment: Note that you will often get product that sits fairly close to the center of the spectrum.  The typical Vf is typically much more common that values close to the min and max.  Also if you are driving LEDs in series, this problem more or less becomes mitigated just by that.

Comment: The forward voltage drop also depends on the device temperature, so it will vary, unless you have a temperature stabilization. To drive an LED you will want to use a current source.

Comment: @Ali Chen:  These LEDs are rated at a maximum of 30mA, so 20mA seemed a reasonable target.  My ultimate purpose is a theatrical candle-like effect, but I simplified the details to try to keep the question focused on what to do, in general, when there's a big possible range of forward voltages.

Comment: Those with enough rep should vote to close this as a duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/341267/led-with-wide-forward-voltage-range?rq=1 which I didn't find until after I submitted this one.

Comment: Or this one:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339458/led-forward-voltage-is-a-range-so-how-do-you-calculate-resistor-value?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have a 3.3V supply and that I want to drive one of these
>   LEDs at 20mA.

In a production environment you do not use an LED with a max V<sub>f</sub> greater than the supply voltage.  In a home project you can give it a try.

The solution is to select an LED with a V<sub>f</sub> that does not exceed the supply voltage.

---

> How do you design a circuit to accommodate such a wide range of
>   forward voltages

Many manufactures "bin" LEDs by V<sub>f</sub> so you can buy your LEDs based on a range of forwards voltage.

An example below is where Samsung packages (bins) the LEDs in 3 ranges of V<sub>f</sub>.

[image]

---

> What factors affect the actual forward voltage?

- Current
- Temperature
- Manufacturing variation

Most LED datasheets will have an IV graph showing the typical V<sub>f</sub> at a specific temperature.

[image]

LEDs have a negative temperature coefficient. For example the V<sub>f</sub> of an LED may decrease 0.006V for every degree rise in temperature. 
LEDs are typically specified to work where the ambient temperature is between -40° and +85° C.  With a 6mV coefficient the V<sub>f</sub> will fluctuate 0.75V across its operating temperature range.

[image]

LEDs are manufactured by growing epitaxial crystals on a substrate. So by the nature of the manufacturing process the V<sub>f</sub> can vary even when the LEDs come from the same wafer.

Comment: +1 for data on temperature dependence. It would be useful to add that, if driven at constant-voltage Vf, there could be a thermal runaway situation, and "magic smoke" will follow.

Comment: You are Inconsistent on text with specs on tempco you ought to say -3 mV/‘C +\-1 not -6mV. Although Vf max/min tolerances are more consistent around typ.  +0.4/-0.2, +0.3/-0.2, 0.2/-0.1

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I added the graphic after writing the text.  6mV is a very common temperature coefficient.

Comment: @AliChen Thanks.  I do not understand the thermal runaway with a CV supply. As I understand thermal runaway it refers to LEDs wired in parallel with a CC supply.

Comment: I always run >=4S MCPCB strips in parallel  strings on CV for long cables without thermal runaway because I know the critical factors. The  equivalent NTC has a  negative ESR dependent on Rja for ‘C/W and matching of ESR for current sharing needs to be less than thermal ESR otherwise wire resistance must be added to reduce the % error and have stable current sharing . This means I might have a 0.5V-1V wire loss on AWG16 so I raise supply voltage according to load with fairly well balanced ESR and equal brightness for my fence luminaries and no runaway.

Comment: @Misunderstood, runaway: let's look at your i-v function, and say you feed the LED at 2.8V. You have 100 mA, or 280 mW dissipated. The die heats to 50C, and the i-v curve shifts left by 150 mV, so the current now is ~200 mA driving the dissipation to ~600 mW. The chip gets even more hot, another 150 mV shift, current jumps to 400 mA, etc, something like that. There may or may not true runaway, but the final working point will be way outside the power dissipation capability of LED package. Smoke will come.

Comment: @AliChen I hope you are not implying someone would drive LEDs with a CV source without a resistor or CCR.  You have a math error.  2.8V x 100 mA does not equal 280 mW of heat.  Radiant efficiency of new LEDs is now about 80-60% and have excellent thermal resistance.  So worst case would be 2.8V x 0.100A x  40% dissipation = 112 mW heat.  With minimal thermal management the temperature would rise less than 1 °C decreasing Vf only a few mV.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist LEDs do not have an ESR making your word salad comment even more incomprehensible.  Keep in mind the topic is supply voltage vs Vf of which your imaginary ESR, wire length, and wire gauge has zero relevance.  KISS rather than  incomprehensible.  Please.

Comment: *"I hope you are not implying someone would drive LEDs with a CV source without a resistor"*. I do. The CV concept and the concern about variations in Vf does imply that. Hypothetically.

Comment: @Ali , very few know the criteria for thermal runaway. I always ensure to have enough thermal conductance and wire resistance and well-matched ESR's to ensure this product is greater than the negative thermal voltage rise with power. I don't suggest anyone drive in parallel but it is done many times successfully when this criteria is met.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist how does one select "well matched ESR's" when there is no such thing as ESR for LEDs?  Oh, that's how YOU do it.  The rest of us match Vf which is a characteristic that is actually in an LED datasheet.  So you convert the Vf in the datasheet to your mythical ESR for no discernible reason?

Comment: ESR is simply a good linear expression of behaviour over a limited range. Your logic has a false assumption

Comment: I spent a good deal of effort getting factories to supply me with matched ESR’s which is an equivalent way of saying Vf=3.0 to 3.1 @20mA but my way describes the component physics like “EMF” instead of voltage . Both are accepted in my profession, but may be foreign to those unfamiliar with similar equivalent terms Ron, Zzt and Rce for other semiconductors which are published in datasheets where important.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist You say: "ESR is simply a good linear expression"  An LED has "instantaneous resistance" or "dynamic resistance".  LEDs do not have anything that resembles "linear resistance" over any measurable period of time.  Vf is in a constant state of change.  So why would you waste "a good deal of effort" (and the company rep's time) trying to get matched ESR when you could have simply asked for a Vf binned part?  I do not believe your story.  Which manufacturer?  What part number?  Name of the rep?  Phone number?  I want to call the rep and ask "Can I get matched ESR LEDs?".

Comment: You have no concept of  linear regression Zzt Rce and RdsOn . All consistent with ESR. Don’t get sidetracked

Comment: I do not and have no need  for a "concept of linear regression Zzt Rce and RdsOn" because those CMOS characteristics  have nothing to do with epitaxy silicon on sapphire photonic devices.   Where very thin crystalline silicon, silicon germanium, or germanium layers with unique well-defined dopants are grown on a sapphire substrate at very low growth temperatures.  Conventional silicon wafers use a higher temperature, non-growth deposition, and different dopants.  Is there a difference between the Vf of a zener diode vs an LED?  Why?  Technical papers use R dynamic or R instantaneous, NOT ESR!

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist in addition to the above ESR serves no purpose.   If a "typical ESR" were used it would still be a I-ESR curve.  The only use of this imaginary ESR of yours would be to calculate the Vf. Is it not easier to just use the Vf?  Technically the resistance of an LED is never constant for any measurable period of time. Due to the dynamic nature of an LED the resistance is in a constant state of change.  As the resistance changes the current and or temperature changes.  As temperature or current changes the resistance changes. An LED approaches but never reaches equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value of the typical voltages are 2.55V and 3.14V for the maximum values. However, plugging in the same resistor value for a 2.2V LED vs a 4.0V LED would be very different currents and brightness levels.

[image]
Source: https://www.lumex.com/article/led-color-guide

> Suppose I have a 3.3V supply and that I want to drive one of these
>   LEDs at 20mA. Based on the 2.7V typical forward voltage, I'd use a 30
>   Ohm resistor. But if I end up with an LED that actually has a forward
>   voltage of 4.2V, it won't light because 4.2V > 3.3V.

The typical forward voltage means that the LED will be lit, how much depends on the LED itself and even the construction of the LED (viewing angle ECT) (not to mention that the human eye sees some colors better than others, so even two LED's with the same intensity will not be perceived at the same intensity).

The only way I've found to really get LED's with the right intensity are to ball park the resistors then fine tune the values based on the intensity, sometimes I'll get a few people to look at it if it's on a product.

The other way is to use a constant current driver, which is more complicated, but allows you to avoid a voltage drop if you can't afford it:

[image]
Source: https://hackaday.com/2012/03/08/led-tutorial-demystifies-several-control-techniques/

Answer (score 1):

LEDs should be driven with nominal current. This is how people accommodate for wide Vf differences.

The simplest circuit is to have much higher (than Delta-Vf) voltage supply and use a resistor of corresponding value. Then the smaller variations in Vf will not change the supply current much, and LED emission changes will be negligible for human eye. But this is not very energy-efficient solution.

A better way is to have a CC (constant-current) source, there are several circuits posted on EE.

Linear CC sources are not efficient solutions, so for medium-to high power LEDs a CC driver based on switchers should be used.

If a resistor or a CC source drives a LED, the forward voltage will appear automatically in accord with LED's inherent I-V diagram, so nobody really cares much about what it is.

More, with 20-30 mA and around 3.3 V, the heat dissipation of this LED will be about 100 mW, which will cause substantial rise of die temperature given the tiny plastic case and no heat transfer path. LED's I-V do have substantial dependence on die temperature, and the Vf will change by another 0.2V.

You just can't control the Vf, and the manufacturing variance in Vf is <strike>largely a don't care</strike> "for information mostly" parameter.

Comment: Really?  Vf is largely  a don't care?  I'm going to have to disagree with you on that.

Comment: @Misunderstood, of course it is not completely "don't care", you need to account for it and have sufficient room in CC LED driver for Vf, whether for individual LEDs, or in-series. It probably would be better to say "for information mostly".

Comment: +1 for sticking to the important issues without a lot of suppositions.

Comment: I manufacture strips with strings of 16 LEDs and the Vf has a 2-3V spread.  I will know if my CC driver has sufficient overhead only if I take the LED's manufacturing Vf variance into consideration.  Not for "information mostly" but an absolute necessity for proper design.

Comment: @Misunderstood, right, but you only need to know the maximum, to build in sufficient overhead. So the "spread" would be still for "information". A good DC-DC CC switcher-driver will take care of the rest.

Comment: But I still MUST know the maximum Vf to design or select a CC driver.  The efficiency will decrease if I use a driver with a supply voltage too far over Vf.  I do not absolutely need the spread except maybe for switching frequency and inductor selection with a simple CC switcher (e.g. AL8862).  I absolutely need the max Vf.  The spread was to illustrate that the manufacturing tolerance on an LED is significantly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

- There is no change in Vf for white colour temperature, that is purely a control of the phosphor layer over blue LED substrate
- Your document from a 3rd party supplier copied from some unknown source has a typo error in the published specs for Vf

### Vf typ should read Vmin

- LEDs like all diodes, zeners and saturated transistor switches starts from a "knee shaped" threshold Vt (or Vzt in Zeners) is obvious from VI charts.
- What causes the voltage to rise above this depends on how small the chip is and some fabrication controls.

  - the slope of rising current is steeper for bigger chips ( and also different scales in VI plots)
- size of the chip and thus the package power rating are inversely related to the slope of the VI curve.
- the slope increases with chip size suitable increased power dissipation in the package. above the  Vf max is only due to the diode "bulk" resistance
- when saturated all diodes have this effective series R, ESR and ESR=k/Pmax
- although the datasheet does not specify this I/V slope or "typ" VI plot  due to wide manufacturing variances

  - i.e. quality controls, yield, cost of large epi-wafer and many 2nd sources which may be qualified  by a cost saving factory and also historically from supplier process improvements
- The wider spread is on the high side of Vf so a White LED might be
  3.0V +0.4/-0.2V
  or +0.2/0.1V
  or single bin +/-.1V or less
- **or WORSE as in your case** with a spread
  of 1.5V from 2.7 to 4.2V. which I believe is
  **3.2V +1.0/-0.5V**
  *But again I believe these are bogus specs. , mislabelled & no test conditions*  I expect this should be

### old info

ESR nom.  varies from 1 / Pmax to 0.25 / Pmax for the best higher power LEDs typ.

So a 5mm 65 mW LED = 15 Ohms typ and a 1W LED is 1 Ohm typical while 3W LEDs are <1/3 Ohm typ. while the best power LEDs are 1/4 of that per diode.

For a Vf using a white 5mm LED at 20mA with Vf=Vt(3mA)+ESR*If   @25’C

Assuming Vt~2.8 @2mA.   (knee threshold voltage, Vt or ~10% of If nominal current.

ESR= (Vf-Vt)/20mA
For Vf = 3.1,3.4
ESR = 15, 30 Ohms

15 Ohms is the expected nominal value of a white 5mm 65mW part.

I would never accept this part with a spec of 4.2V even if the supplier said this was actually at 30 mA.

ESR =(4.2-2.8)/30mA=47 Ohms or 3x the nominal “good quality” value.    This is equivalent to +300% tolerance unacceptable by today’s standards. And most likely another error in the spec.

The same inverse power to ESR relationship  is true for silicon diodes.

Here are some 1/3W 5050 LEDs
[image]
- best sources are few but exist

If you prefer 100 % single bin White,
This is what I used to sell and still have some leftover  in 200 pc bags.
 3.0-3.1V @20mA
 30 deg 16,000~20,000 mcd ( too bright to watch at close range )
 4000’K ~4500’K
( also similar in Red, Yellow, Blue, true green , Aqua)

Comment: I think he's referring to the "Min", "Typical" and "Max" values for Vf at rated current.  IIRC these typically fall on a fairly tight, centered bell curve and often improve with manufacturing methods.  If this is the case, these are simply the Vf range a diode has to test rated current within before being accepted as "good" by the factory, and the Vf(typical) would be one of the averages (mean, median or mode)

Comment: LEDs do NOT have an ESR.

Comment: Yes when saturated above ~10% of Imax the linear bulk resistance dominates over the quadratic curve such that Vf =Vth+ESR* If is a good fit to any diode curve and ESR std deviation is an epitaxial quality figure of merit.

Comment: Anyone who says "LED's don't have ESR" does not understand. It's like saying transistor switches don't have Rce and MOSFET's don't have RdsOn and Zener's dont have Zzt

Comment: @KH  It very tight (1%) within one epitaxial wafer but on some suppliers very loose between batches (+50/-25%)

Comment: Some of the best information on this site ends up in the comments =).  This is really good to know for someone like me who deals with small quantities of chips.

Comment: My comments are consistent with other answered asymmetric tolerances . But these data sheet specs have wrong header for Vf typ

Comment: I don't understand???  You are the only source that I have seen that uses ESR when referring to LEDs.  Not only that, if an LED did have an ESR it would not relevant to the OP's questions.  Show me one LED datasheet that uses the term ESR.  You are WRONG.  Again.

Comment: You can ignore ESR if you prefer but I find it very useful to understand behaviours and spot errors in data sheets such as this .  You won’t find Rce in all data-sheets except when Zetex started to. But you always find Zzt which is ESR in zener diodes. I did this even before Zetex (Diodes Inc) started doing this for switching BJT’s.  How specs are released has nothing to do with the physics that exists here.

Comment: And you will NEVER find ESR in an LED datasheet.  I'm sorry, I do not find ESR useful but rather find it annoying, unnecessary, and confusing to the issue.  The Vf max is not do to your imaginary ESR variation it is simply due to a variation in Vf which is not an imaginary characteristic, it is the characteristic actually used in LED datasheets.

Comment: Well then you don’t understand the physics of bulk resistance vs power capacity.

Comment: Except you are using the term ESR not Bulk Resistance.  LEDs do NOT have an ESR.  Capacitors have ESR. The characteristics of an LED do not have the characteristics of a device with an ESR value.  Show me a credible link to anything (book, article, technical paper, datasheet) that uses ESR in reference to an LED.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance

Comment: Use Rb rather than ESR and I will drop it even though it is still not the correct term used.  I will call you out every time you use ESR because it is an incorrect term to use.  The terms used when referring to an LED's resistance is usually R instantaneous or R dynamic.  I have read at least a dozen books and hundreds of technical papers on LEDs, NEVER have I seen the term ESR used in reference to an LED.  NEVER!  It makes zero sense to use the resistance of an LED over Vf.

Comment: You now say: "The same inverse power to ESR relationship is true for silicon diodes".  Except the term ESR does not apply to "silicon diodes" either. LEDs are a silicon diode. To understand the difference between traditional CMOS fabrication and LED fab, I suggest you read Chapter 12 (Fabrication of Silicon Photonics Devices) of "Handbook of Silicon Photonics" by Vivien.  LED fab is similar to CMOS image and temperature sensors, ADCs, and charge pumps.  And not so similar to schottky or zener diodes.   Remember NEITHER traditional diodes or LEDs have an ESR.  Please.  Capacitors have ESR.

Comment: You say "Vf typ should read Vmin".  NOT true!  I have found most LEDs I have used (mid and high power) the actual Vf is lower than typical.   Also your comment "15 Ohms is the expected nominal value of a white 5mm 65mW part" is so wrong on so many levels it is beyond my comprehension how you arrived at such a ridiculous conclusion.

Comment: You say "This is what I used to sell and still have some leftover in 200 pc bags. 3.0-3.1V @20mA".  You previously said "I spent a good deal of effort getting factories to supply me with matched ESR’s which is an equivalent way of saying Vf=3.0 to 3.1 @20mA"  Which is it?   Vf=3.0 to 3.1?  Or some ESR.   I can understand you insisted on buying by ESR rather than Vf.  I just cannot believe you really did, but rather made it up in support of your mythical LED ESR.  What was the ESR of the LEDs you purchased?  How did it read on your purchase order?

Comment: I'm very curious.  Why did you buy binned bags of 20 mA LEDs?  How were they wired?  Parallel, series or both?  If both how many in parallel?  How many total were used in what kind of product? But the big question is why?  Why bin 20 mA LEDs?

Comment: Customer requirements were typically 30k~50kpcs per order 16k~20k mcd and matched brightness, color and voltage.  Wireless power 5S4P arrays for tunnel sidewalk and road illumination, German stds also qualified by Philips Illumination.  So I chose the best sources to my specs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a bit confused because LED's are current driven devices. To some degree the 'typical' forward voltage is at a typical safe drive current, while maximum forward voltage could be the peak pulsed current the LED can handle, but not have a long life.

I buy 5mm round high-efficiency pure white LED's that put out 1 watt of light while consuming about 1/9th watt of power. Forward voltage is 2.9, which is the minimum turn-on voltage, to a maximum of 3.5 volts.

I know I need at least 2.9 volts to make them dim, and limit or fix the current depending on how long I want it to last vs. brightness. The manufacture states that 20 mA continuous or 30 mA pulsed @ 10% duty cycle are typical **maximum** current values.

So ultimately you have a voltage source high enough to turn the LED on full but you limit the current by using a current sink or clamp or a fixed resistor tied to a fixed voltage source. I run mine at 15 to 16 mA in blocks of 25 so I need a 75 volt source just to turn them on.

But my source is 1/2 wave 120 VAC so my source is about 85 volts. A few K ohms of resistors limits the current to a safe 15 to 16 mA. Future version may include a current sink to lock the LED current even if the source voltage fluctuates. Please read @laptop comment and link to some useful current sinks and clamps.

It is important to understand that typical forward voltage must be combined with a safe drive current, usually 2/3 of the rated maximum value so the LED will run cool and have a long life. If you run it in pulsed mode take 2/3 of the maximum pulsed current limit as a good safe value.

LED's **do not care** about the source voltage as long as it is above its minimum rated voltage. **They do care a lot about the drive current** from this voltage source. Try not to get voltage and current confused.

Comment: You stated " put out 1 watt of light while consuming 1/9 th of power ". Watts are not a magnitude of light intensity, and getting more power out from a system than what you're putting in violates the 1st law of thermodinamics, you can't get power out of nothing!

Comment: LEDs have a non-linear resistance profile, which varies even between components made out from the same silicon die, but the voltage across a LED does matter and will determine a given current acording to the earlier mentioned resistance profile.

Comment: There's a nominal driving current where the LED complies with the manufactuter stated specifications such as a given color profile. Driving LEDs with any other arbitrary current like  2/3 the manufacturers claimed maximum wouldn't make sense unless you were trying to achieve a specific goal by doing so. As regards a LED runing cool and having a longer life, that would depend not only on the LED power but on the juntion to ambient thermal resistance, which would vary according to the chosen design.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude! Sorry for that. I viewed the details I pointed out as important, maybe not so much to you because you readily knew what you were talking about, but I believe users searching for answers in this posts might find those sentences misleading!

Comment: @JuanManuelLópezManzano  Watts are not a magnitude of light intensity?  When Sparky said "1 watt of light" he was being very specific that the watt was a measurement of light and not electrical power.   According to the SI system of units Radiant Flux is measured in Watts.  Radiance and Radiant Intensity are also measured in watts,  watt per steradian and watt per square meter steradian respectively.

Comment: +1 in support for experience and against senseless nit-picking.

Comment: @Misunderstood If you think you can get 1 watt of light out of an LED by putting 1/9 watt of power in, you are _NOT_ using "watt", the unit of radiant flux, you are using "watt", the colloquial unit of approximate incandescent bulb equivalence, which is a very different unit.

Comment: @GlennWillen  I was addressing Juan's comment saying "Watts are not a magnitude of light intensity".  I do NOT think I can get 1 watt of light with 1/9th watt of electricity.  I didn't want to get into Sparky's magical LED issue.  He did say "1 watt of light" which could be a correct use of watt if referring to radiant flux.  Getting 1 watt of light from 1/9th watt of electricity does defy the laws of physics.  I prefer the quantum units of µmol/s.